# Error converting varchar to numeric error in SQL Server inside CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL :

```
DECLARE @HTMLROWSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @ContractTerm NVARCHAR(20)

SET @ContractTerm = 2
SET @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract = 1

SET @HTMLROWSSingle  = '<tr>' + CASE WHEN @ContractTerm = 2
                                   THEN @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract  * .50 
                                   ELSE 1 
                                END + '</tr>'

Select  @HTMLROWSSingle
```

I am getting an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

If I change the SQL to

```
SET @HTMLROWSSingle = CASE WHEN @ContractTerm = 2
                         THEN @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract * .50  
                         ELSE 1 
                      END
```

I am able to get the data. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Here is the fiddle `http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca0ba/2836`

Thanks

Comment: When ContractTerm = 2 should be  When ContractTerm = '2' because it is nvarchar not int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to combine a string with a number. You need to turn the number into a string as well. Try

```
DECLARE @HTMLROWSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @ContractTerm NVARCHAR(20)
SET @ContractTerm = 2
SET  @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract = 1

SET @HTMLROWSSingle  = '<tr>'+ CAST(Case When @ContractTerm = 2
          Then 
         @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract  * .50 Else 1 End as nvarchar(50)) +
         '</tr>'

Select  @HTMLROWSSingle
```

Comment: Since the `@HTMLROWSSingle` variable is of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` datatype, I'd recommend to use `NVARCHAR` in the `CAST` around the `CASE`, too, to avoid unnecessary implicit conversions

Comment: @marc_s I agree - missed that.  I updated my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should always use the right datatypes when using some calculation with them. In this case, you are trying to concatenate a string with a decimal value directly, hence getting a conversion error.
You should use something like this instead:

```
DECLARE @HTMLROWSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @ContractTerm NVARCHAR(20);
SET @ContractTerm = N'2';
SET @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract = 1

SET @HTMLROWSSingle  = '<tr>'+ 
                        Case 
                            When @ContractTerm = N'2'
                            Then CONVERT(NVARCHAR(18),@UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract*.50) 
                            Else N'1' 
                        End +'</tr>';

Select  @HTMLROWSSingle;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast those values into `varchar/char`, since you are trying to concatenate those values:

```
DECLARE @HTMLROWSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @ContractTerm NVARCHAR(20)
SET @ContractTerm = 2
SET  @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract = 1

SET @HTMLROWSSingle  = '<tr>'+ Case When @ContractTerm = 2 Then  cast(@UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract  * .50 as nvarchar(10)) Else cast(1 as nvarchar(1)) End + '</tr>'

Select  @HTMLROWSSingle
```

Comment: Since the `@HTMLROWSSingle` variable is of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` datatype, I'd recommend to use `NVARCHAR` in the `CAST` around the `CASE`, too, to avoid unnecessary implicit conversions

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @HTMLROWSSingle NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract decimal(18,2)
DECLARE @ContractTerm NVARCHAR(20)
SET @ContractTerm = '2'
SET  @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract = 1


SET @HTMLROWSSingle  = '<tr>' +  
        CASE 
            WHEN @ContractTerm = '2'
        Then 
         TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @UnrecoveredPercentageOfTotalContract  * .50 )
         ELSE TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),1)
         END + '</tr>'

Select  @HTMLROWSSingle
```